# Shopware 6 change shipping method programmatically in checkout on order submission

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

I have two of same shipping methods with different price matrix, depending on customer distance, one of the two shipping method should be selected. This has to be done programmatically on checkout order confirmation, I looked at the cart collector, but it's about changing price of an item. I didn't find anything covered in documentation regarding shipping method change.

Following is my attempt to change it `onOrderValidation`.

```
private function getShippingMethod(string $id, Context $context): ?ShippingMethodEntity
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter("id", $id));
    $criteria->setLimit(1);
    $result = $this->shippingMethodRepository->search($criteria, $context);
    return $result->getEntities()->first();
}

    public function onOrderValidation(BuildValidationEvent $event)
{

    $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($this->salesChannelContext->getToken(), $this->salesChannelContext);

    $delivery = $cart->getDeliveries()->first();

    //test


    $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethod($this->getShippingMethodZoneXId(), $event->getContext());
    
    $delivery->setshippingMethod($shippingMethod);

    $cartDeliveries = new DeliveryCollection();

    $cartDeliveries->add($delivery);

    $cart->addDeliveries($cartDeliveries);

    $this->cartService->setCart($cart);
    
    ...

}
```

In the above code I have `cart` object, and `delivery`. I get the shipping method which I need to set, but it doesn't get updated.

Also i need to recalculate shipping price, what is the correct way to do it. any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update:** I have also tried from shopware doc [collect/process](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-processor-collector), but that also didn't work.

```
public function collect(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
{
    $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethod($this->getShippingMethodZoneXId(), $context->getContext());
    $shippingMethodId = $shippingMethod->getId();

    $key = self::buildShippingKey($shippingMethodId);

    $data->set($key, $shippingMethod);
}

public function process(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, Cart $toCalculate, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
{

    // change delviery

    $deliveries = $this->builder->build($toCalculate, $data, $context, $behavior);

    $deliveryOriginal = $deliveries->first();
    
    if($deliveryOriginal === null) {
        return;
    }

    $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethod($this->getShippingMethodZoneXId(), $context->getContext());

    $deliveries->first()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

    $this->deliveryCalculator->calculate($data, $toCalculate, $deliveries, $context);

    $toCalculate->setDeliveries($deliveries);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely ended up with another approach, none of the above seem to work for me. Item price updation was taking place but not shipment.

So here's what you need, this `contextSwitcher` dependency i injected and it did the job. `update()` method that can be used to switch shipment method.

```
SalesChannelContextSwitcher $contextSwitcher,
```

Comment: Hi, did you inject it in a subscriber or in the cart processor?

Answer (score 2):

For all that can't find the solution for this:

I've created a service to handle that. This function is setting the $shippingMethodId to the given one.

```php
public function changeShippingMethod(string $shippingMethodId, SalesChannelContext $context)
    {
        $contextToken = $context->getToken();

        $dataBag = new DataBag([
            'shippingMethodId' => $shippingMethodId,
        ]);

        $this->contextSwitcher->update($dataBag, $context);
    }
```

Don't forget to add the use statements

```php
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContextSwitcher;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\DataBag;
```

and a constructer

```php
private $contextSwitcher;

public function __construct(
    SalesChannelContextSwitcher $contextSwitcher
) {
    $this->contextSwitcher = $contextSwitcher;
}
```